# Upload photo to a facebook fan page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

here's my code keypoints that I'm using in order to upload photo to my fan page

```
_permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", @"manage_pages", @"user_photos", @"friends_photos",nil] retain]; 

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/accounts" andDelegate:self];
```

I parse the page access_token from results and use it for next requests impersonating page, and I can successifuly parse out page owner info from the result, so I guess my access_token is ok

```
 - (IBAction)getUserInfo:(id)sender {
            _facebook.accessToken = self.pageAccessToken;
          [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
        }
```

But If I try to upload photo to my page album like this:

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {

          NSString *path = @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxxxx/Icon.png";
          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
          NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
          UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

          NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         img, @"picture",
                                         nil];



            _facebook.accessToken = self.pageAccessToken;


          [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];

          //or like
          // [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" ...
          // [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/<PAGE_ID>/photos" ...
          // [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/<ALBUM_ID>/photos" ...

          [img release];
        }
```

I always get error:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=190 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 190.)" UserInfo=0x15fca0 {request_args=(
{
key = method;
value = "photos.upload";
},
{
key = sdk;
value = ios;
},
{
key = "sdk_version";
value = 2;
},
{
key = "access_token";
value = "1939755xx612731|8ceab6c65ce0194d079f41ef-1068726246|3x2697618282|xdSRakxsdjezx9N1dnr9cRe6ICk";
},
{
key = format;
value = json;
}
), error_msg=Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token, error_code=190}

}
```

(note: i've modified slightly access_token just for protection)

Comment: Could this be a permissions issue in Facebook? Do you have permission to post/upload photos?

Comment: well, i think so. if I impersonating page I guess page have that permission by default

Comment: look pretty much like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259573/posting-photos-to-facebook-fan-page-with-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey jackiedigital, I this the "manage_pages" permission is only compatible with the Graph API.
Check out the Last permission on this page:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/