# facebook ios sdk - upload photo to fan page

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to upload/post a image to a facebook fan page, which isn't owned by me

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You should see this post in the link down there:

[Posting photos to Facebook fan page with iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259573/posting-photos-to-facebook-fan-page-with-ios-sdk)

Comment: did you read the post you linked to? it looks like the author of that post didn't get a meaningful answer himself. Or did it work for you?

Comment: @KostiantynSokolinskyi i've posted a solution at that post today.

Comment: @arsalan thanks, I will try it out today and tomorrow and will leave a comment

Comment: Any luck?  Seems like the offered solution only allows admins to post to the page not any random user.