# Sharing hyperlink with facebook from iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to share text, picture and url with facebook using following code.

```
_lblTitle.text=@"Joe just ran 3.10 miles on the Niagara Falls 5k in 24.53 with http://www.outsideinteractive.com";

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _lblTitle.text, @"name",
                                   data, @"picture",
                                   nil];

    // Make the request
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                            if (!error) {
                              // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                              NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"result: %@", result]);
                            } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                              NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.description]);
                            }
                          }];
```

But now I want to share hyperlink (text having link).

**Example:**
Joe just ran 3.10 miles on the Virtual Niagara Falls 5k Course in 24.53 with [Outside Interactiive](http://www.outsideinteractive.com).

**Currently I am able to share like this:**
Joe just ran 3.10 miles on the Niagara Falls 5k in 24.53 with http://www.outsideinteractive.com

Note:I am also sharing picture in current functionality, And I want to continue with that.

**Desired Result:**
[image]

Comment: how did you solve this. pleas share the code or link which solves your problem. I have to do the same task. but could not find a helpful link. I tried  to work with html string but could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                           @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                           @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                           @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                           @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                           nil];
```

You can make a dictionary like this and pass this to your function which will contain what exactly you want

Or something like this

```
FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/"];
params.name = @"Sharing Tutorial";
params.caption = @"Build great social apps and get more installs.";
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png"];
params.description = @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.";
```

Comment: thanx, but I have already tried this way. And I am getting result like I have added in my question under tag "Dont want to share like this". Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot I got the solution. This is possible only by **Facebook Open Graph Story**.

You will have to create custom Story using Facebook Developer Website and integrate it properly with your ios app.

Follow this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph) to create custom story.