# Facebook URL Scheme for iOS - post photo

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, photo, facebook-page

There are many URL schemes that can be used for facebook on iOS.

Is it possible to use one of these URL schemes to post a photo to a fan page?

I was trying to use `fb://publish/photo/(initWithUID:)/(aid:)/(pid:)` and `fb://upload/(initWithSource:)/profile/(uid:)` without any luck.

I'm not sure what to use for the `initWithSource:`.

Has anyone had any success in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShareKit framework to share the images to Facebook.
All you need to do is simple as following.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:myImage title:@"Title"];
SHKFacebook *sharer = [[[SHKFacebook alloc] init] autorelease];
[sharer loadItem:item];
[sharer share];
```

ShareKit is very useful and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea from here and then merge this code in your own code as per on your requirement [Post Photos on fan page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259573/posting-photos-to-facebook-fan-page-with-ios-sdk)