# Getting page_access_token by graph api in FBConnect ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Actually i want to upload photo on facebook fan page so for this i wrote below code

```
[m_facebook setAccessToken:@"BAAGgxy3PqqcBAHqByi2JOtTs .....8SCo8MK22y0smcFnxFEt7U6zVP2U4WpLrpnDWNuwXpvSYB9Btt7ZCMljBGmfxgPKoOdmadmNitSZB47trDv9hXd4wAE3VjZBbWBGMPP1lV8H1rfTcXNRuX8ePqRhxXsAypA7uHkSVyZASp0oaVfY0sJF55O8agZDZD"];

[m_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"437...6356137/photos"
                               andParams:fbArguments
                           andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                             andDelegate:self];
```

With above code i am able to post photo on my facebook fan page but the problem is **i have to hard code Page_Access_Token** as you can see so can any one tell me that **how i can access this Page_Access_Token token dynamically using FBConnect**. I have already went through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259573/posting-photos-to-facebook-fan-page-with-ios-sdk).

Answer (score 1):

You have to authenticate by this line

```
NSArray *permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", @"manage_pages", @"user_photos", @"friends_photos",nil] retain];
[facebook authorize:FB_APP_ID permissions:permissions delegate:self];
```

Once you get authenticated , you will get `AccessToken` via this delegate method

```
  - (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt
{
      //Use access token
}

 - (void)fbDidLogin {
[self.facebook1 accessToken];//you can access token once you get this call back.
```

}

**Note:** When you call `extendAccessToken` to extend token, the above delegate will call in that time too. `fbDidLogin` delegate method call when you get first time authentication. `fbDidExtendToken` delegate method get call when you try to extend access token. `accessToken` will get expired depending on expirationDate.

Comment: is am i getting PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN IN THIS delegate

Comment: Now see my edited code. It'll help you ... Even now if you don't get that call back, you have to check with your delegate method.